# Difference between tokensToSend() and OperatorSend()?

Tags: erc-777

I read eip777 but have no idea what's difference between tokensToSend() and OperatorSend().
Could you please clarify them for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERC-777 defines two functions to send tokens:

- `send(address to, uint256 amount, bytes calldata data)`
- `operatorSend(address from, address to, uint256 amount, bytes calldata data, bytes calldata operatorData)`

The first one is used when the owner of the tokens wants to transfer them, whereas the second one is used by an *operator* to send tokens on behalf of the token owner. Operators are essentially the equivalent of ERC-20's allowance. The `operatorSend` function is the equivalent of `transferFrom`, it can transfer tokens from an address of a token owner, to another address (assuming that the caller is an operator).

If you want to send tokens from your address, use `send`. If you want to send tokens from another address, use `operatorSend` if you are an authorized operator.

`tokensToSend` not a "regular" function in ERC-777, but a *hook* function. Hooks can be registered in the [ERC-1820](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1820) registry, and must be called by the ERC-777 contract before completing a token transfer (either through `send` or `operatorSend`). The `tokensReceived`  hook is called in the context of the sender (e.g. a token owner), and can be used to "cancel" the transaction.

The whole process for sending tokens in ERC-777 looks something like this:

[image: ERC-777 hooks]

1. The sender calls `send(to, amount, data)` with the receiver's address, amount, and (optional) data.
2. The token contract calls `getInterfaceImplementer(address, interfaceHash)`, with the address of the sender and the interface hash of `ERC777TokensSender` (`tokensToSend` hook).
3. If an implementation is specified, the token contract calls `tokensToSend(operator, from, to, amount, userData, operatorData)` on the implementing contract.
4. The token contract calls `getInterfaceImplementer(address, interfaceHash)` again, with the address of the receiver and the interface hash of `ERC777TokensRecipient` (`tokensReceived` hook).
5. If an implementation is specified, the token contract calls `tokensReceived(operator, from, to, amount, data, operatorData)` on the implementing contract.

This assumes that both the sender and receiver are contracts (to keep it simple), but the same idea applies to transactions from a regular address to another regular address (except that the addresses would specify a contract as implementer for the hooks).

If you're interested, I wrote a detailed explanation of ERC-777 (as well as ERC-20 and ERC-721) [here](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-technology-behind-ethereum-tokens-5615527e1af8).